# VHDL textio, reading image from file

Tags: image, file, vhdl, fpga

I am trying to learn how to implement image processing algorithms in an FPGA and to do this I am working with a txt file that contains a bmp image (converted using MATLAB).

I am havin problems using the textio package, so by now I am only able to read the first column of data (but not the entire row of data).

The txt file have this aspect:

```
    1,1,0,0,0
    0,1,1,1,1
    1,0,0,0,0
    0,0,1,1,0
    1,1,1,1,1
```

a 5x5 matrix separated by commas.
The output of the entity I have now in my simulations is

```
    1 0 1 0 1
```

that corresponds to the first column.
I don't understand why the code doesn't read all the line and when it ends jump to the next line.

Here is the process for read the file (I have add a variable named comma so I could detect the comma and skip it but still doesn't work ):

```
reading : process 

    constant filename : string := "C:\DOCUMENTACION\PROYECTOS\Envio_salida_VGA_atraves_FPGA\MatLab\Procesado de imagen con Toolbox\prueba.txt";
    file f : text open read_mode is filename;
    variable L : line;
    variable data_read : integer;
    variable comma : character;
begin
    while not endfile(f) loop
        wait until rising_edge(clk); 
            readline(f, L);
            read(L, data_read);

            while L = ',' loop
                read(L, comma);
            end loop;

            d_out <= data_read;
    end loop;
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you considered driving the stimulus into simulation directly from SW rather than going through a file? This Python based example handles bitmaps, jpegs, tiffs etc. and automatically compares similarity of the output: https://github.com/chiggs/oc_jpegencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I don't understand why the code doesn't read all the line and when it ends jump to the next line.***

You're only trying to read one integer then one comma before the next `readline`.

Also note as long as you can count on one character separating consecutive integers on a line you don't have to care what the character is (and you don't so much as look at `comma`).

To read every integer on a line you need to pay attention to whether your `read` calls have consumed all the line buffer.

I modified your code to demonstrate after saving your example data to a file named prueba.txt:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity prueba is
end entity;

architecture foo of prueba is
    signal d_out:   integer;
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
begin
reading:
    process
        constant filename:  string := "prueba.txt";
        file f:              text open read_mode is filename;
        variable L:          line;
        variable data_read:  integer;
        variable char:      character;  
        variable len:       integer;  
    begin
        while not endfile(f) loop
            readline(f, L);

            len := L'length;
            while len > 0 loop
                read (L, data_read);
                len := L'length;
                if len > 0 then
                    read (L, char);
                    len := L'length;
                end if;
                wait until rising_edge(clk); 
                d_out <= data_read;
                report "data_read = " & integer'image(data_read);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
        wait;                   
    end process;
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 250 ns then -- picked by prueba.txt number of elements
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Because a resulting waveform requires you count clocks or time instead of datums I added a report statement which gives:

> prueba.vhdl:33:17:@5ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@15ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@25ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@35ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@45ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@55ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@65ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@75ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@85ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@95ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@105ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@115ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@125ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@135ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@145ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@155ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@165ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@175ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@185ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@195ns:(report note): data_read = 0
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@205ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@215ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@225ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@235ns:(report note): data_read = 1
>   prueba.vhdl:33:17:@245ns:(report note): data_read = 1

Where we find all the integers in prueba.txt are read.

Note I added a variable named `len` to hold the number of characters available in `L`.  Every `read` or every `readline` `len` gets updated.  If there are no more characters on the line we don't try to read.

The evaluation of `Now` in the `CLOCK` process and the extra `wait until rising_edge(clk);` and following `wait` in the `reading` process are just to stop the simulation where a waveform would be useful.

---

We use `L'length` to tell us if there are any more datums on a line or whether we should fall out into the outer `while loop` and call `readline` if not at the end of the file.

You could also note the process can be re-written using only the `'length` attribute:

```
reading:
    process
        constant filename:  string := "prueba.txt";
        file f:              text open read_mode is filename;
        variable L:          line;
        variable data_read:  integer;
        variable char:      character;  
    begin
        while not endfile(f) loop
            readline(f, L);
            while L'length > 0 loop
                read (L, data_read);
                if L'length > 0 then
                    read (L, char);
                end if;
                wait until rising_edge(clk); 
                d_out <= data_read;
                report "data_read = " & integer'image(data_read);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
        wait;                   
    end process;
```

And this gives the same answer. We'd use a `len` variable if we were to do something clever like throw away comments, which would also require we scan `L` and trim trailing white space. We can assign values to `len` but not `L'length`. Because there is nothing trailing the last datum in your prueba.txt we can simply use the `length` attribute.

Comment: I tried to run this code snippet and it works fine (as you show) but I still doesn't understand some parts: why "len" has to be defined again inside each if and while parts? I tried to avoid this, but then it doesn't work and I am not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

L is a pointer to a string.  To de-reference the pointer, you need:

```
L.all
```

Hence, to get a character, you can do:

```
L.all(1) = ','
```

As a shorthand, you can also do:

```
L(1) = ','
```

Answer (score 0):

You can study this package which contains a dynamic sized array type of up to 3 dimensions that can load/save both from/to csv and raw files.

https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/blob/master/vhdl/array/src/array_pkg.vhd

It is part of the VUnit VHDL testing framework.